# SQL Server select record with different id but same value in multiple tuples

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has a location ID, product ID, and tech ID.  I want to be able to find instances in the data where one location has different product ID for two different tech IDs.  Here is an example of what I would like to find.

```
|Location ID | Product ID | Tech ID |
+------------+------------+---------+
|Location 1  | Product 1  |Tech ID 1|
|Location 1  | Product 1  |Tech ID 2|
|Location 2  | Product 1  |Tech ID 1|
|Location 2  | Product 2  |Tech ID 2|
|Location 3  | Product 1  |Tech ID 1|
|Location 3  | Product 1  |Tech ID 2|
|Location 4  | Product 3  |Tech ID 1|
|Location 4  | Product 3  |Tech ID 2|
```

From this example, I would want to to find Location 2 because the Product is different.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your example illustrates this "one location has different product ID", but what does this mean?   "for two different tech IDs."

Comment: @TabAlleman It means the location is using two different products for the different tech IDs at one location.

Comment: So to be clear, if a location had 2 different Product IDs, but the Tech ID was the same for both, you would NOT want to return that location?

Comment: @TabAlleman correct.  That would be something else and not my intent here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way that should perform very well:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable 
  WHERE t1.LocationID=t2.LocationId
  AND t1.ProductID<>t2.ProductID
  AND t1.TechID<>t2.TechID
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--SELECT THE DISTINCT Location ID from the sub query
SELECT DISTINCT x.[Location ID]
FROM
(
   --Sub query to Group by LocationId and Product ID, along with Row_Number
   --TO get an integer value of which records have more than one 
   --when grouped by locationId and productId, if Row Number > 1 it means there are more than one record
   --for same location id (so there are different products)
   SELECT [Location ID], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Location ID] ORDER BY [Location ID]) AS 
[RowNumber]
   FROM TABLE
   GROUP BY [Location ID], [Product ID]
) AS x
WHERE x.[RowNumber] > 1
```